# How can you search for all tables with a given column name and return which tables have this column name in Hadoop/Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am looking to find all tables that contain a given column name in HDFS/Hive?

Answer (score 0):

As of now i guess there is no direct way to find a table which has the particular column in hive.

But i would suggest using the hive metastore for this purpose , if it would suffice your requirement.

In case if your hive metastore is configured in mysql , then there are 2 tables TBLS - which has all the tables in your hive and COLUMNS_V2 which has the column names of all tables.

So basically join theses 2 tables for finding the table with column name .

Hope this helps.