# Search for a Column Across All Hive Tables

Tags: hadoop, hive

I need to check if a particular column exists in any of the HIVE tables across all databases or at least in one database inside Hive.

The same question has been asked before before a year but I feel things might have changed and there might be direct solution:

[Similar question asked before but does not solve my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273589/how-can-you-search-for-all-tables-with-a-given-column-name-and-return-which-tabl)

I did try querying TBLS and COLUMNS_V2 from Hive CLI but it threw an error:

> SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:14 Table not found 'TBLS'